# Gmail displaying border for HTML newsletter

Tags: html, gmail, newsletter

I'm doing a newsletter in HTML and GMAIL is always displaying a border on the following table :

```
        <tr>
          <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 20px 0 20px 0;margin:20px 0 20px 0;height:150px;">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="60%">
              <tr>
                <td align="center" style="padding: 20px 0 20px 0; color: #000000; font-family:Helvetica,verdana,sans-serif;border-top:5px solid;border-bottom:5px solid;solid;border-color:#000000;">
                    <span style="font-size:24px;padding: 0 0 0 0;color:#000000;"><b>THE MILAN DESIGN WEEK CONTINUES IN BRERA !</b></span>
                </td>                       
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
          <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 10px 20px 20px 20px;">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <img src="DCW_RAW_1.jpg" alt="DCW éditions lampes Gras at Raw Brera" width="560" height="382" style="display: block;" />
                </td>                       
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

Could anyone explain me why ?

Here is a JSFiddle of the code

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1o561qmv/)

Thanks a lot !

Comment: are you seeing this only in specific browsers? or does viewing the email through gmail in IE, Chrome and Firefox all have the same result?

Comment: I don't get it, the jsfiddle specifies: style="border: 1px solid #cccccc;"

Comment: I've tried with different browsers (Firefox, Chrome and IE) and they all have the same result. Also, i tried to add *{border:none;} to the top of my CSS and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Try adding `table { border-collapse:collapse }` to your css